# I'm looking for an example on how to use select.select() with subprocess to monitor stdout

Tags: python, select, subprocess

Basically, I have an application that is loaded using

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I can send it commands using p.stdin.write() without any trouble, but I need to monitor stdout for server responses. this whole thing is running inside a tcp server, so I need to know if select.select() is going to stop execution when its called. I also can't find any example code using select.select and I find the manual page to be a little confusing. Could someone here offer some advice on this?

Answer (score 0):

A non-None `timeout` parameter will make sure that `select()` doesn't block.

Comment: I'm not sure what that is. Can you add details? :X

Comment: The fourth argument to the function.